# Check whether username is already in database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am creating a help desk where one can create a new account. If the username is already in the database, you should get a message that tells you to take another username.
If the username is correct, the password must be provided with a hash before the data is entered in the database.

I have already searched for an answer via the internet but I don't find anything that works in my program.

```cs
//Declaratie private variabelen
        private int _klantnummer;
        private string _gebruikersnaam, _voornaam, _achternaam, _straatEnNummer, _postcode, _gemeente, _telefoonnummer, _email, _wachtwoord;
        private bool _admin;

        //Publieke eigenschappen
        private int Klantnummer
        {
            get { return _klantnummer; }
            set { _klantnummer = value; }
        }

        public string Gebruikersnaam
        {
            get { return _gebruikersnaam; }
            set { _gebruikersnaam = value; }
        }

        public string Voornaam
        {
            get { return _voornaam; }
            set { _voornaam = value; }
        }

        public string Achternaam
        {
            get { return _achternaam; }
            set { _achternaam = value; }
        }

        public string StraatEnNummer
        {
            get { return _straatEnNummer; }
            set { _straatEnNummer = value; }
        }

        public string Postcode
        {
            get { return _postcode; }
            set { _postcode = value; }
        }

        public string Gemeente
        {
            get { return _gemeente; }
            set { _gemeente = value; }
        }

        public string Telefoonnummer
        {
            get { return _telefoonnummer; }
            set { _telefoonnummer = value; }
        }

        public string Email
        {
            get { return _email; }
            set { _email = value; }
        }

        public string Wachtwoord
        {
            get { return _wachtwoord; }
            set { _wachtwoord = value; }
        }

        public bool Admin
        {
            get { return _admin; }
            set { _admin = value; }
        }

        //Default Constructor
        public Klant()
        {
            Klantnummer = 0;
            Gebruikersnaam = "";
            Voornaam = "";
            Achternaam = "";
            StraatEnNummer = "";
            Postcode = "";
            Gemeente = "";
            Telefoonnummer = "";
            Email = "";
            Wachtwoord = "";
            Admin = false;
        }

        //Constructor met parameters
        public Klant (string pGebruikersnaam, string pVoornaam, string pAchternaam, string pStraatEnNummer,
            string pPostcode, string pGemeente, string pTelefoonnummer, string pEmail, string pWachtwoord,
            bool pAdmin)
        {
            this.Gebruikersnaam = pGebruikersnaam;
            this.Voornaam = pVoornaam;
            this.Achternaam = pAchternaam;
            this.StraatEnNummer = pStraatEnNummer;
            this.Postcode = pPostcode;
            this.Gemeente = pGemeente;
            this.Telefoonnummer = pTelefoonnummer;
            this.Email = pEmail;
            this.Wachtwoord = pWachtwoord;
            this.Admin = pAdmin;
        }

        //Constructor met parameters met klantnummer
        public Klant(int pKlantnummer, string pGebruikersnaam, string pVoornaam, string pAchternaam, string pStraatEnNummer,
            string pPostcode, string pGemeente, string pTelefoonnummer, string pEmail, string pWachtwoord,
            bool pAdmin)
        {
            this.Klantnummer = pKlantnummer;
            this.Gebruikersnaam = pGebruikersnaam;
            this.Voornaam = pVoornaam;
            this.Achternaam = pAchternaam;
            this.StraatEnNummer = pStraatEnNummer;
            this.Postcode = pPostcode;
            this.Gemeente = pGemeente;
            this.Telefoonnummer = pTelefoonnummer;
            this.Email = pEmail;
            this.Wachtwoord = pWachtwoord;
            this.Admin = pAdmin;
        }
```

Comment: Could you add any add/remove/CRUD method you tried to create yourself?

Answer (score -1):

What I usually do is make the username field unique in the database then use a try...catch on the call to the database. If it fails for a unique validation error I know the username was already used and respond to the user.

Comment: @mason How would you intend to accomplish that?

Comment: @mason And if a user is added to the database after you check and before you insert the new user?

Comment: @mason Using a transaction solves nothing.  The select doesn't prevent a new user of that username from being added.  So you're proposing a solution that's slower, has bugs built into it by design (with potentially extremely serious consequences if/when they manifest), and will only get worse and worse over time as the number of users (and if things go well, the application as a whole) grows, all because you just don't like the idea of using exceptions?  That's rather counter productive.

Comment: "The goal with the select isn't to prevent a user with that username from being added, it's simply a check to make sure the username isn't already taken."  The purpose of checking if it's taken is to prevent them from being added in that case.  The larger the application the greater the odds of the bug manifesting.  The potential exists even small applications.  If you want to claim that the exception isn't necessary then you'd need to provide a solution that *actually solves the problem*.  Your proposed solution still leaves the bug there.  If you can propose another tool *that works*...

Comment: @mason Why do you think an exception on a database query in the case that there is a conflict is going to be slower than performing *an additional database query on every single request, regardless of whether there is a conflict or not*?  And to claim it's unnecessary you'd need to provide a solution that solves the problem without using it.  You haven't done so.